# Extracticting String from List in an Object where a field is repeated on other objects List in Python

Tags: python, list

I currently have a List of objects each object is like this:

```
{"version": "4.6.1604", "models": ["N3NVRPOE"], "filename": "v4.6.1604.0000.206.0.1.39.3_20220316", "url": "http://files.northernvideo.com/FTP/NTH/N3NVR%20FIRMWARE/4-8-16ch/v4.6.1604.0000.206.0.1.39.3_20220316", "user_manual": "http://www.northernvideo.com/pdf/NTH-N3NVRPOE-SERIES_v1.pdf", "vendor_metadata": {"product_family": null, "model": "New N3 NVRs & Kits", "northern_status": null, "os": null, "landing_urls": ["http://www.northernvideo.com/newn3nvrskits.html", "http://northernvideo.com/newn2sdipcameras.html"]}, "description": "N3 Series H.265 -4, 8, 16 & 32 Channel NVR's with POE ", "device_picture_urls": "http://www.northernvideo.com/images/430_N3NVR_Stacked_Cropped.png"}
```

In this case the list of this objects has a 9 objects and each object has a field called url, and a field call models (which is a list as well), the problem I'm having is that I need to go object by object checking the URL field, and if the URL is duplicated extract the model and added to the one left for example I have 6 with the URL: *http://files.northernvideo.com/FTP/NTH/N3NVR%20FIRMWARE/4-8-16ch/v4.6.1604.0000.206.0.1.39.3_20220316* I will need to delete 5 and keep one with all the models of the deleted 5.

Any ideas?

Kind Regards

I tried at the moment of insertion do a validation via if's but when used like that it doesn't fill the primary list.

Comment: It's a dictionary. Can you change it to a dataframe and iterate over it using pandas? I think you can.

Comment: Also add expected outputs

Comment: @SorooshNoorzad It's not a Python dictionary. It's JSON

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

- I would use a dictionary, e.g. called `url_to_obj`
- I would loop through the list of objects
- For each object in the list, I would insert it into the dictionary and if the url is already present, then I just append the models
- Finally, at the end of the loop, if you prefer to have a list instead of a dictionary, you can easily get `list(url_to_obj.values())`